# Answering to a mailing list

Tags: email, mailing-list

This might be a dumb question but I really can't figure out how to reply to ANY existing thread or post on the llvm mailing list (http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/llvmdev). As far as I've understood I can post threads to llvmdev@cs.uiuc.edu, but how to reply to one particular post? There's no reply button, not even in the google groups page I'm subscribed to